# processing a list in an elegant and quick manner for duplicates

Tags: c#, list

dI have the below code to check for the existance of a duplicate filename and deleting the files with their duplicates.

I can do so by looking for the first and last index in the first list then checking if it's not the same. List item contains an object with a name and ID. There are around 550k objects in list.

the second loop has filesPaths list with around 5k filepaths. If theres a duplicate file and it is in this second list then I can delete.

The below operation takes over a day to complete. Is there some way to shorten that time?

```
foreach (DocNameObject someObjectDataFileRow in someObjectDataFileList)
{   
  int index1 = Array.FindIndex(someObjectDataFileList.ToArray(), row => row.docName.StartsWith(someObjectDataFileRow.docName));
  int index2 = Array.FindLastIndex(someObjectDataFileList.ToArray(), row => row.docName.StartsWith(someObjectDataFileRow.docName));

  Console.WriteLine(++i);
  if (index1 != index2) 
  {
    foreach (String fileName in filesPaths)
       {
         try
         {
            if (fileName.Contains(someObjectDataFileRow.docName))
            {
               if (File.Exists(fileName))
                 File.Delete(fileName);
            }
         }catch (Exception e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem deleting:" + e.Message);
         }
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Can your list have 2 different files with the same filename? 2. Can it exist more then two records with the same filename? 3. Do you need to delete all records with the same filename except the first record filename?

Comment: 1. yes. Starting with the same filename I can have files like fileName-1,fileName-2...  2. In the first list fileName doesnt differentiate like it does in the second list. Its same but yes there can be multiple rows of same fileName. The point is to find those multiples, then delete them from the real directory. 3. All records if theres a duplicate of it.

Comment: Does order matter in the list, also does case sensitivity matter?

Comment: Apparently it does. After I ordered the list and checked if next item has the same docName, the operation completed in 15 minutes. The problem was the index comparisons or the array conversions. I'll check back in a bit after a test.

Comment: The reason I asked if order mattered was I thought I had a solution using HashSets, but when I re-read the question I realized I missed the 2nd part about the file deletes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that you could do is to sort the "someObjectDataFileList" based on the docName. It might make the computation of index1 and index2 redundant.

Another optimization is to delete the fileName also from the 'filePaths' list, once it is physically deleted.

Answer (score 1):

On the quick thought you could use `for(...)` loop instead of `foreach(..)`, so you will always have index1 without additional computations, and after that, you can use:

```
public int FindIndex(int startIndex, Predicate<T> match)
```

so you will be looking for duplicates in the right part of list, because the left part from the index would be already checked.

Another thing is `.ToArray()` convertion. You could convert the enumeration just once, not on every single cycle.